# Get the Column Names of a Stored Procedure when using BCP QueryOut

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the BCP QueryOut working fine, but now my question is how to get the header row of the stored procedure in the request.  I can `UNION` the header row in the SP, but I run into a problem...  And the header rows cannot change, ie `000000` to be on top, etc..

Here is the stored proc:

```
 SELECT 'col1','col2'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY Name
```

this won't work because the `ORDER BY` ruins the first row being the header row.  So I'm wondering if there is another way around this?  The main focus is getting the header row to come up in the text file (on the Top) when using BCP QueryOut command.

Comment: Check out this article http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2008/10/10/export-to-excel-with-column-names.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it forces sorting to work

```
SELECT 'col1', 'col2'
UNION ALL
SELECT Name1, MAX(Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Name)
FROM table
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51e5f/1)

Answer (score -1):

use a sub-query:

```
SELECT 'col1','col2'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY Name )
```

Comment: Thanks, but already tried that.. Get this error: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.